# In how many days did the work get completed given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> N,R and V can complete a piece of work in 10,15 and 12 days.All the 3 of them started working and after the integral number of days(y) N stopped working and R stopped working exactly (y) days before the work got completed.If the number of days taken to complete is an Integer.In how many days did the work get completed.

options:

a) $6$  b) $8$ c) $7$  d) $10$

MyApproach:

N did=10% R did=6.66% and V did=8.33%

Together they did 25% work.

They did this for y no of days=25 . y% Let y =2

Remaining work  $100$-$25 . y$ %

N stopped working after y no of days

=>Remaining work is done by R+V=15% work they do in 1 day 
and R stopped working exactly (y) days before the work got completed.

I am unable to use the above equations.How to approach the problem?Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is simple: y can only be 1, 2 or 3. Consider each situation and you get the answer.